# Orion refuses to start (location.coords_2dsphere index error)

Tags: fiware-orion

After upgrading to Orion 0.22.0 (applying [the documented migration procedure](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Upgrading_to_0.21.0_and_beyond_from_any_pre-0.21.0_version)), Orion refuses to start, existing with the following message:

```
INFO@10:51:50  contextBroker.cpp[1191]: Connected to mongo at mongodb1:27017:orion 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'mongo::OperationException'   
   what():  OperationException: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "Index with name:
location.coords_2dsphere already exists with different options", code: 85 }
```

I'm using a MongoDB replica set as database.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue (which we have been observed sometimes in replica set environments) is to remove the location.coords_2dsphere index, i.e. executing the following command in the mongo shell (connected to the primary node):

```
db.entities.dropIndex({"location.coords": "2dsphere"})
```

In the case of using Orion in [multiservice mode](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Multi_service_tenancy), you have to apply the above command to each one of the tenant databases.

Orion will re-create the index next time it starts.